# "Go get it" for sportsmanship lists questions where mine is the only answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, sportsmanship-badge

The Sportsmanship badge is about upvoting other people's answers where you yourself also have an answer.

Now, I think "Go get it" on this kind of badge is questionable to begin with (i.e. it encourages artificial upvoting), but - it exists. The thing is, the questions it lists include questions where you've given the only answer, so you can't upvote anybody else.

Comment: That button literally just takes you to a list of your own answers on your profile - there isn't any special filter applied. There is no list anywhere of answers you've given where other answers exist.

Comment: I think this wwould be nice as a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

> The thing is, the questions it lists include questions where you've given the only answer, so you can't upvote anybody else.

You could contribute an answer to a question that is already answered and upvote the current answer. Of course your answer must be quality as you need your own answer to get an upvote for it to count.

> it encourages artificial upvoting

I think the point is to give you an incentive to vote for question you may be in competition with to recieve acceptance by the OP.